# Custom Core Data SectionNameKeyPath

Tags: ios, core-data, transient, sections

I am new at core data and am trying to figure out how to create a custom `sectionNameKeyPath` in my `NSFetchedResultsController`. I have a managed object with an attribute called `acctPeriod`. It is a `NSString`. I want to create sections based on the first 4 characters of this field. The first 4 characters represent the year of the accounting period and doesn't need to be saved.

I have gone through this site and have seen posts about transient attributes but I can't seem to get them to work. Basically I want this and then assign `periodYear` for my `sectionNameKeyPath`.

```
@dynamic periodYear;

-(NSString *)periodYear
{
    return [self.acctPeriod substringToIndex:4];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:
Using Martin R. answer, I was able to get it to work as expected.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Billing" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Set the batch size to a suitable number.
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

// Edit the sort key as appropriate.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"acctPeriod" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

//Predicate
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"clients = %@", self.client];
NSLog(@"%@",pred);

//[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
//[fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"periodYear" cacheName:nil];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return _fetchedResultsController;  
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The following should work: Implement the `periodYear` method (which will be used
as "section name key path") in a class extension of your managed object subclass:

```
@interface Event (AdditionalMethods)
- (NSString *)periodYear;
@end

@implementation Event (AdditionalMethods)
- (NSString *)periodYear {
    return [self.acctPeriod substringToIndex:4];
}
@end
```

Make sure that `acctPeriod` is used **as the first (or only) sort descriptor** for the fetch request:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"acctPeriod" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Use `periodYear` as `sectionNameKeyPath` for the fetched results controller:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                  initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                   managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext 
                     sectionNameKeyPath:@"periodYear"
                              cacheName:nil];
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;
```

And finally add the default `titleForHeaderInSection` method:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo name];
}
```

Alternatively, you can define `periodYear` as *transient attribute* of the managed object.
It will also not be stored in the database in that case, but can be implemented in a way that the value is calculated on demand and cached.

The [DateSectionTitles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project from the Apple Developer Library demonstrates how this works.

Comment: OK, that worked great. I tried this before but the problem is that I'm trying only to load 1 of my entities, acctPeriod, and sort it by periodYear. So I was using 
    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"acctPeriod"],nil]];
which doesn't seem to work. I tried to put periodYear as entityProperty but I know that it's not. I get this error: 'Invalid keypath periodYear passed to setPropertiesToFetch:' Any thoughts?

Comment: @theDVUSone: If you use `propertiesToFetch` then you probably have to define `periodYear` as transient attribute and add it to the `propertiesToFetch`. I did not try it, but that is what I assume.

Comment: I was making the mistake of declaring a @property that implemented a getter. This solution more or less pointed out that it should just be a method declaration.

Answer (score 10):

I recommend against using a transient property as the `sectionNameKeyPath` as it will result in faulting all objects obtained by the fetch request just so the property could be used as the section path.
You better define a persistent property of `year` and use it as your `sectionNameKeyPath`.
set you FRC `sectionNameKeyPath` to `year` like so:

```
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"year"
                                               cacheName:nil/*your chioce*/];
```

to display the section name as a title in the table, implement:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sec = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sec name];
}
```